# How to read a jasmine spec file config variable from the jasmine.json file

Tags: node.js, jasmine, config

I am learning the node.js jasmine code testing framework and would like to set a variable that will be reused in several test spec files.  Is there a way to read a config variable from the jasmine.json file?

I have used the 'process.env.npm_variablename' for normal package.json node.js config variables, but that file is not loaded by the jasmine test runner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part way through typing the question, I thought of a solution that seems to be working: load the file with the 'require' function.  It looks like this in the initialized current 2.6 jasmine structure:

```
var jas_config = require('./support/jasmine.json');
if (jas_config.verbose_output) {
    console.log("loading test-spec.js");    
}
```